# GitHub Action Cherry Pick Commit and Push as GitHub App

Tags: git, github-actions

I am trying to write an action that will cherry pick commits from main and add them to uat and develop branches. I have branch protection rules setup and have added a GitHub App to allow it to bypass the protection rules.

However, when I push it still says I am the Author and the branch protection rules kick in. How do I push as the GitHub App?

```
name: Sync

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      from:
        required: true
        type: string
      to:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  Cherry-Pick:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Setup Environment
        uses: <Org>/<Repo>/actions/setup-environment@main
        with:
          app-id: ${{ vars.ACTIONS_APP_ID }}
          private-key: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_CERTIFICATE_KEY }}

      - name: Cherry Pick Commits
        run: |
          branches=("develop" "uat")
          git fetch origin --prune
          for branch in "${branches[@]}"
          do
            if git show-ref --verify --quiet refs/remotes/origin/$branch; then
              echo "Branch $branch exists. Cherry picking commits..."
              git checkout $branch
              git -c user.name=${{ vars.ACTIONS_APP_NAME }}[bot] -c user.email=${{ vars.ACTIONS_APP_ID }}+${{ vars.ACTIONS_APP_NAME }}[bot]@users.noreply.github.com cherry-pick ${{ inputs.from }}..${{ inputs.to }}
              git push --force-with-lease origin $branch
            else
              echo "Branch $branch does not exist. Skipping..."
            fi
          done
```